# Preformat date from database before compare with date from user input in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an table where I'm storing downloads of the user, columns - `created_at` and `updated_at`.
What I'm trying to do is simple filter where I can choose from datepicker From-To dates and show all downloads for given time range.

This is what I have in my function

```
$dateStart = new DateTime($request->startDate); // '2022-02-01'; 
$dateEnd = new DateTime($request->dateEnd); //'2022-02-08'; 
        //dd($dateStart);
        
$downloadsbyuser = DB::table('downloads')
   ->select('user_id as downloader_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count_by_user_id'))
   ->whereBetween('downloads.updated_at', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])
   ->groupBy('user_id');
```

So, in database, the columns are defaultfor laravel and `timestamp`. The date coming from datepicker is in `2022-02-01`.

This is what I have in database

```
ID  user_id   created_at             updated_at
1   34        2022-02-06 10:17:39    2022-02-06 10:17:39
2   34        2022-02-08 10:17:39    2022-02-08 10:17:39
3   20        2022-02-02 10:17:39    2022-02-05 10:17:39
4   34        2022-02-02 10:17:39    2022-02-05 10:17:39
```

When I search dates `2022-02-01` to `2022-02-06` as you can see I should get 3 results - ID's 1,3 and 4 but instead I've got 2 results. When I search `2022-02-01` to `2022-02-07` then I've got correct 3 results but this means that if there is entry with date `2022-02-07` it wont show.

Why is this happen? Is it because of the `whereBetween` clause?

Comment: I think adding time to your date variables should solve the problem.

Comment: But I don't want to add time on datepicker. Just select dates from the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MySql `date_format` function!

```
$dateStart = new DateTime($request->startDate); // '2022-02-01'; 
$dateEnd = new DateTime($request->dateEnd); //'2022-02-08'; 
        
$downloadsbyuser = DB::table('downloads')
   ->select('user_id as downloader_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count_by_user_id'))
   ->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(downloads.updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"), [$dateStart, $dateEnd])
   ->groupBy('user_id');
```

Comment: Same error as on other answer - `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DB::raw(DATE_FORMAT(downloads.updated_at)' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Try now. @JasonWung

Comment: Now another error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ','%Y-%m-%d' between ? and ? group by user_id)` the query `(select user_id as downloader_id, COUNT(id) as count_by_user_id from downloads where DATE_FORMAT(downloads.updated_at),'%Y-%m-%d' between 2022-02-01 00:00:00 and 2022-02-06 00:00:00 group by user_id) `

Comment: Now is working and the download has all 3 records. Thanks

Comment: @JasonWung I've updated the ans. It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL DATE function

```
$dateStart = new DateTime($request->startDate); // '2022-02-01'; 
$dateEnd = new DateTime($request->dateEnd); //'2022-02-08'; 
//dd($dateStart);
$downloadsbyuser = DB::table('downloads')
   ->select('user_id as downloader_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count_by_user_id'))
   ->whereBetween('DATE(downloads.updated_at)', [$dateStart->format('Y-m-d'), $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d')])
   ->groupBy('user_id');
```

Comment: Column not found - `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE(downloads.updated_at)' in 'where clause'`. Without `DATE` no such error

Comment: does it MySQL or PostgreSQL ?

Comment: It is `MySQL`..

Comment: Still - `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE(...)`

Comment: $dateStart = new DateTime($request->startDate);
this code seems to be not ok, its returning php object not date string. it should be like this 
$dateStart = new DateTime($request->startDate);
$dateStart->format('Y-m-d')